# Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for Three Sets

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

If $|A\cap B|= \varnothing $ (disjoint sets),

then $|A \cup B|=|A|+|B|$

Using this result alone, prove $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|$

$|A\cup B| = |A| + |B - A|$

$|A\cap B| + |B - A| = |B|$,

summing gives

$|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|$.

In the same way, prove:

$$|A∪B∪C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A∩B| - |B∩C| - |A∩C| + |A∩B∩C|$$

---

$|A∪B∪C| = |A|+|B-A|+|C-B-A|$

$|A∩B| + |B-A| = |B|$

$|C-A| + |A∩C| = |C|$

$|C-B|+|+|B∩C|=|C|$

$|C-B-A| + |C| = |C-A|+|C-B|+ |A∩B∩C|$

summing the previous five equations gives

$|A∪B∪C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A∩B| - |B∩C| - |A∩C| + |A∩B∩C|$

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you provide more information about what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I would look at it this way: for any point p, one and only one of these is possible: (a) p is in all three or A, B, and C.  (b) p is in both A and B but  not C. (c) p is in both A and C but not B. (d) p is in both B and C but not A.  (e) p is in A only.  (f) p is in B only.  (g) p is in C only. (h) p is in none or the sets.  Now define 8 sets, each consisting of all points that satisfy one of the 8 conditions.  Number the points of each of those sets.

Comment: *Hint:* $A\cup B\cup C = A\cup (B\cup C)$ and remember that $B\cup C$ is itself a set and acts just like any other set.

Comment: To elaborate on @JMoravitz's point, try defining set $D=B\cup C$ and using the third principle you stated.